# Make active cell a hyperlink to newly created tab

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, so I am trying to make a macro that will allow users to hit the button, type their name into the input box, copy a worksheet template, move that new worksheet to the end of the book, rename it to match their name, and update the index sheet with a hyperlink showing their name on the list that jumps them to cell A4 on their sheet. The hyperlink part is where I'm struggling, although I also need some error handling for the rest of it. I have tried a variety of solutions, but I can't make it work for me.

```
Sub CopyIIDTemplate()

    Dim MySheetName As String



    MySheetName = InputBox("Please type your first and last names.")

    Sheets("Template").Copy after:=Sheets("Template")

    ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName

    ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = MySheetName

    ActiveSheet.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

    Sheets("Index").Activate

    Sheets("Index").Range("B51").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Activate

    ActiveCell = MySheetName

    Sheets("Index").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Excel.Selection, Address:=ActiveCell.Value, SubAddress:="'" & Sheets("Index").ActiveCell.Text & "'!A4"



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating hyperlinks, the `Address` parameter should be blank for a location within the existing workbook, and the `SubAddress` parameter can be created using your `MySheetName` variable rather than the invalid `Sheets("Index").ActiveCell.Text` (invalid because the `ActiveCell` is the active cell - it's not a property of a `Worksheet` object).

A refactored version of your code would be:

```
Sub CopyIIDTemplate()
    Dim MySheetName As String
    MySheetName = InputBox("Please type your first and last names.")

    'Make a copy of the "Template" sheet and place it after the last worksheet
    Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

    'Use a "With" block to make typing easier (i.e. we can use
    '".xxx" instead of "Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).xxx" everywhere
    'within the block
    '
    'Worksheets.Count gives the number of worksheets in the workbook.
    'Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) therefore gives the last worksheet
    'in the workbook, which is where we placed the copy of "Template".
    With Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        'Set this sheet's name
        .Name = MySheetName
        'Set cell B1's value to be the person's name
        .Range("B1").Value = MySheetName
    End With

    'Use another "With" block to save typing.  This time we are
    'using the cell one row below the last non-empty cell above cell
    'B51 on the worksheet called "Index".
    '
    'Note: Using Range("B" & Worksheets("Index").Rows.Count) instead of
    'Range("B51") may be better - that would find the last non-empty cell
    'in the entire column B.
    '
    With Worksheets("Index").Range("B51").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        'Set the cell's value to be the person's name
        .Value = MySheetName

        'Add the hyperlink
        '
        'Anchor (i.e. where to place the hyperlink):
        '".Cells(1,1)" when applied to a range will give the top-left
        'corner of the range.  The range that we are applying it to is
        'a single cell, so this will simply point to that same cell.
        'It would have been nice to be able to just say "." to point to
        'the cell, but that would undoubtedly not work.
        '
        'Address (i.e. file/url to refer to):
        'Just use "" for a reference to the existing workbook
        '
        'SubAddress (i.e. location within the Address):
        'Need to create an address similar to "'Ian'!A4"
        'Wrap the person's name in "'" characters, so that embedded
        'spaces don't cause issues, and then stick a "!A4" at the end.
        '
        'Note: If the person's name contains any "'" characters (e.g.
        '"Antonio D'amore") the simplified version used here won't work
        'because "'Antonio D'amore'!A4" actually needs to be
        '"'Antonio D''amore'!A4", but let's ignore that for now.
        '
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                        Address:="", _
                        SubAddress:="'" & mySheetName & "'!A4"
    End With
End Sub
```

Note:  If any of your staff have a `'` in their name, the subaddress parameter will need to be `SubAddress:="'" & Replace(mySheetName, "'", "''") & "'!A4"`.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Question, though: How does `With Worksheets(Worksheets.count` identify the new sheet? Also, can you break down the hyperlink code you provided? It works, but I don't understand it entirely.

Comment: @user4907546 - I have added a lot of comments to the code - hopefully it will give some insights into what is happening and why.  Feel free to ask more questions if what I have written doesn't explain it.

Comment: That helps me understand that code a lot better. Thanks for taking the time to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is incorrect reference in the last line:

```
Sheets("Index").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Excel.Selection, Address:=ActiveCell.Value, SubAddress:="'" & Sheets("Index").ActiveCell.Text & "'!A4"
```

Replace `Sheets("Index").ActiveCell` with `ActiveCell` and it should work.